# Should I return true/false in JQuery Ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if my code should have return statement in my AJAX function. Here is example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Application.cfc?method=runProcess',
    data: {'userID':userID},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS == 200){
        $('#searchMsg').addClass("success").show().text(obj.MESSAGE).delay(3500).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("success").dequeue();
        });
        return true; //Should I keep this
    }else{
        $('#searchMsg').addClass("error").show().text(obj.MESSAGE).delay(3500).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
        });
        return false; //Should I keep this
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

As you can see I have two return statements in my function. Both will return either true or false depends on the ajax return obj. Should I keep them in my function or not? What is benefit of having them and what are the cons? If anyone can explain please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you be the one to tell us what the pros and cons of them would be?  You'd be the one to know how they might be use in your application.

Comment: @Taplar I don't need them in my function but I see a lot of examples where they use them. So I just want to understand what are the pros and cons of having them or not. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't need them, remove them.  If you need them later, add them.  Though how are you expecting to use them, since ajax is asynchronous?

Comment: The only purpose the return statement serves in a .done callback is to stop further code within the callback from running. In your case the return is at the very end of each case such that removing it would not result in more code running, making their existence negligible. You could however keep the first one, then move the else code out of the else and still have the same result. However, it's no better than simply using an else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Remove them. They do nothing for you. You already have the ability to know if the AJAX call succeeded or failed by which portion of your `if/then` in your callback function you hit.

All these statements do is send a value back to the caller  that the caller then can use as it wishes and stop programmatic execution. Here, the caller is the `done` method call, which isn't expecting any return value and since you have the statements as the last things that will be done in the function, execution will stop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No need for this true or false if you send ajax call to check something and return server is exist they return true else false e.g Login i send ma username and password to database if exist return true than i check if ajax return true mean they user login to the system if false means user not exist but not need for true false if exist you need to open new link else give error not exist its depend on what scenario you want but not necessary to return true false its not compulsory
code example

```
$.ajax({
        url: geturl,
        type: "POST",
        data:{email:email,pass:pass},
        success: function (res) {
            if (res == "admintrue")
            {
                AutoLoader("Admin Login Succeffully", "success");
                var URL = $("#Afetlogin").val();
                window.location.href = URL;
            } else if (res == "membertrue") {
                AutoLoader("Member Login Succeffully", "success");
                var URL = $("#memberlogin").val();
                window.location.href = URL;
            }

            else {
                AutoLoader("Error", "error");
            }
        }
    })
```